# como faço para somar entradas de um tuplo e retorna um tuplo com uma entrada que tem a soma das entradas d tuplo anterior?somar por colunas

Tags: python

[image: as votações][image: 22 entradas]

22 entradas de um tuplo que terá de retornar num tuplo a soma de cada valor na coluna correspondente

Comment: assembelia(votacoes) retorna uma lista de tuplas?

Comment: "Escreva uma função assembleia que dado um tuplo de tuplos votacoes com os resultados da votação em cada círculo
eleitoral, devolve um tuplo com o número total de mandatos atribuído a cada
candidatura na Assembleia da República. Assuma que o tuplo votacoes tem 22
entradas, em que cada entrada é um tuplo com 15 valores, i.e., o número de votos
em cada candidatura." - Já calculei os mandatos atribuidos para cada círculo eleitoral. Falta-me somar todas para obter a nível nacional. Retorna um tuplo

Comment: Tente deixar sua pergunta um pouco mais clara, coloque um exemplo do resultado que você espera.

Comment: >>> assembleia(votacoes)
(0, 16, 137, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 71, 6, 0)                                                           terá de ser essa a resposta

Comment: a partir dessas votações cheguei a esses mandatos e ao fazer o return que me mostrou ele retorna a soma dos votos e nao dos mandatos

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt João. Seria legal vc editar sua pergunta e deixa-la um pouco mais clara, assim a comunidade pode lhe ajudar melhor.

Comment: Ué, se é uma soma das colunas, então minha resposta está certa.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi sua pergunta, precisa somar cada coluna.

Tendo em vistas que votacoes é uma tupla de tuplas, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
def assembleia(votacoes):
    return tuple(map(sum, zip(*votacoes)))
```

O que está acontecendo:

1. estamos passando as tuplas dentro de votacoes para a função `zip`. A gente consegue fazer isso colocando o `*` antes do nome da tupla: `*votacoes`.
2. A função `zip` será a responsável por transpor a sua matriz de votações, isso é, transformar o que era uma matriz de linhas em uma matriz de colunas.
3. Passamos a função `sum`, que soma todos os elementos de um iterável, e a nossa matriz de colunas para a função `map`, que será responsável por aplicar a função `sum` em cada coluna da nossa matriz.
4. Como o map gera um objeto do tipo `map`, passaremos o seu resultado para a função `tuple`, que gerará a tupla que você precisa.

De acordo com seu exemplo:

```
In [1]: votacoes = (
....:     (0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 1, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 1, 11,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 5, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 3, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 2, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 2, 0,),
....:     (0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,),
....:     (0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,),
....: )
In [2]: tuple(map(sum, zip(*votacoes)))
Out[2]: (0, 16, 137, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 71, 6, 0)
```

Comment: como defino o n?

Comment: desculpa, não entedi. O que quer dizer?

Comment: como defino q n é a coluna?

Comment: Vou editar a questão para ficar mais claro

Comment: nao está a retornar o q é pedido. retorna a soma dos votos e nao dos mandatos

Comment: Hmm, então entendi errado a pergunta.

Comment: O que representa um mandato?

Comment: representa um deputado eleito

Comment: mas esses valores nao vao aparecer no shell. Só aparece msm a soma dos mandatos.

Comment: Definitivamente você precisa ser mais claro.